# Phonegap build squashing app once compiled? Why is it doing this?

Tags: javascript, ios, xml, cordova, adobe

I am working for a company creating their app and am using PhoneGap to create the app. I uploaded the correct components to Adobe's phonegap build service and downloaded the IPA file on my iPhone 6+. However when I boot it up it looks something like this:

[image]

as you can see the app is extremely squashed but on the official phonegap app for iOS it works perfectly with no problems; hence making me believe it is something to do with my file structure or XML file. If someone could point my in the right direction for fixing it that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the right splashscreens in your config.xml. If you don't define them you get a smaller screen.

```
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"  src="splash_iphone_5.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334"  src="splash_iphone_6.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208"  src="splash_iphone_6p.png" />
```

Maybe you are missing `<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />` too.